# I am using UNION ALL, then I want ORDER BY globaly

Tags: mysql

Can I order by flt.flt_Date_Start(Globaly union) If its there any solution please help me
Here I try to achieve order by Date Globally Please Help me
Can I order by flt.flt_Date_Start(Globaly union) If its there any solution please help me
Here I try to achieve order by Date Globally Please Help me
Can I order by flt.flt_Date_Start(Globaly union) If its there any solution please help me
Here I try to achieve order by Date Globally Please Help me

```
  (Select
 flt.flt_Id as fltId,
 flttyp.flttyp_Name As FlightType,
 off.off_Name as offName,
 fltrte.fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk As pilot1Id,
 fltrte.fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk As pilot2Id,
 per1.per_Name As Pilot1Name,
 per2.per_Name As Pilot2Name,
 per1.per_Name As GrpPilotName,
 flt.flt_Date_Start as dtStrt,
 flt.flt_Date_End as dtEnd,
 air.air_Id as airId,
 flt.flt_Trip_Rpt_No as rptNo,
 flttyp.flttyp_Id as flttypId,
 flt.flt_Eng_Tim As EngT,
 flt.flt_Flt_Tim As FlyT,
 flt.flt_Wait_Tim As WaitT,
 (select sum(pltfltdtytim.pltfltdtytim_Tot_Dty_Tim) from pltfltdtytim where pltfltdtytim.pltfltdtytim_Flt_Id_Fk = flt.flt_Id and pltfltdtytim.pltfltdtytim_Per_Id_Fk=per1.per_Id) As DutyT,
 flt.flt_Route as fltRout
From
 fltrte left Join
 flt On fltrte.fltrte_Flt_Id_Fk = flt.flt_Id left Join
 off On flt.flt_Off_Id_Fk = off.off_Id left Join
 air On flt.flt_Air_Id_Fk = air.air_Id left Join
 per per1 On fltrte.fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk = per1.per_Id left Join
 per per2 On fltrte.fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk = per2.per_Id left join
 flttyp On flt.flt_Flttyp_Id_Fk = flttyp.flttyp_Id
where
  flt.flt_Status <> 4 and per1.per_Name is not null and per1.per_Name !=''
 Group By
  off.off_Name,flt.flt_Date_Start,
  flt.flt_Trip_Rpt_No, flt.flt_Id, flttyp.flttyp_Name, flt.flt_Route,
  flt.flt_Status

Order By
  flt.flt_Date_Start)     
union all  
(Select
 flt.flt_Id as fltId,
 flttyp.flttyp_Name As FlightType,
 off.off_Name as offName,
 fltrte.fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk As pilot1Id,
 fltrte.fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk As pilot2Id,
 per1.per_Name As Pilot1Name,
 per2.per_Name As Pilot2Name,
 per2.per_Name As GrpPilotName,
 flt.flt_Date_Start as dtStrt,
 flt.flt_Date_End as dtEnd,
 air.air_Id as airId,
 flt.flt_Trip_Rpt_No as rptNo,
 flttyp.flttyp_Id as flttypId,
 flt.flt_Eng_Tim As EngT,
 flt.flt_Flt_Tim As FlyT,
 flt.flt_Wait_Tim As WaitT,
 (select sum(pltfltdtytim.pltfltdtytim_Tot_Dty_Tim) from pltfltdtytim where pltfltdtytim.pltfltdtytim_Flt_Id_Fk = flt.flt_Id and pltfltdtytim.pltfltdtytim_Per_Id_Fk=per2.per_Id) As DutyT,
 flt.flt_Route as fltRout
 From
 fltrte left Join
 flt On fltrte.fltrte_Flt_Id_Fk = flt.flt_Id left Join
 off On flt.flt_Off_Id_Fk = off.off_Id left Join
 air On flt.flt_Air_Id_Fk = air.air_Id left Join
 per per1 On fltrte.fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk = per1.per_Id left Join
 per per2 On fltrte.fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk = per2.per_Id left join
 flttyp On flt.flt_Flttyp_Id_Fk = flttyp.flttyp_Id
where
  flt.flt_Status <> 4 and per2.per_Name is not null and per2.per_Name !=''
 Group By
  off.off_Name,flt.flt_Date_Start,
  flt.flt_Trip_Rpt_No, flt.flt_Id, flttyp.flttyp_Name, flt.flt_Route,
  flt.flt_Status

Order By
  flt.flt_Date_Start)
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question please ? To many "please help me Here I try to".

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do a subselect:

```
SELECT ... dtStrt ...
FROM (
   (SELECT ... as dtStrt, ...
   FROM ... JOIN... WHERE...)
   union all
   (SELECT ... as dtStrt, ...
   FROM ... JOIN... WHERE...)
) as val
ORDER BY dtStrt
```

Comment: Actually, you don't - ORDER BY in a UNION is against the final result set.  MySQL supports an ORDER BY on a per statement basis in a UNION'd statement, but only if the query is surrounded by brackets/parenthesis